# QFileIconProvider returns the same icon regardless of file

Tags: c++, qt, python-2.7, pyside

I am developing an application using PySide (which wraps the Qt 4.8 framework). I need to display icons of applications associated with certain file extensions, and I am using `QFileIconProvider` for this. On Windows, my code works perfectly - every file extension is displayed along with the icon of the appropriate application. However, on Linux Ubuntu (14.04.1), the same code displays the icon for an unknown file extension for all the file extensions I try.

Anyone know why this is happening? Here is the code:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

# Use the appropriate path module when running on Windows.
path = None
import os
if os.name == "nt":
    path = __import__("ntpath")
else:
    path = os.path


class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...
        # ...
        self.file_ext_to_icon = {}

    def get_icon(self, fpath):
        _, file_ext = path.splitext(fpath)
        file_ext = file_ext.replace(".", "")
        if file_ext in self.file_ext_to_icon:
            return self.file_ext_to_icon[file_ext]
        if path.exists(fpath):
            icon = QtGui.QFileIconProvider().icon(QtCore.QFileInfo(fpath))
        else:
            temp_fpath = path.join(os.getcwd(), "myappname_temp.%s" % file_ext)
            if not path.exists(temp_fpath):
                with open(temp_fpath, "wb") as _:
                    pass
            icon = QtGui.QFileIconProvider().icon(QtCore.QFileInfo(temp_fpath))
            os.remove(temp_fpath)
        if icon.isNull():
            # Use a custom default file icon from the resources file. Note that
            # this is different from the default file icon given by the OS.
            icon = QtGui.QIcon(":images/default_file_icon.png")
        self.file_ext_to_icon[file_ext] = icon
        return icon
```

Comment: I had encountered the same problem as well. It's because of Qt/Gtk integration. Qt applications aren't "native" on a Gtk desktop (in the sense of theming, icons, cursors, etc.).The problem should disappear on KDE for example, because KDE is based on Qt.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after much digging here is what I ended up doing...

```
class IconProvider(QtWidgets.QFileIconProvider):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mimeDatabase = QtCore.QMimeDatabase()

    def icon(self, info: QtCore.QFileInfo):
        mimeType = self.mimeDatabase.mimeTypeForFile(info)
        return QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme(mimeType.iconName())


...used in my class
self.filesModel = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel(self.filesView)
self.filesModel.setIconProvider(IconProvider())


...or in your case
icon = IconProvider().icon(QtCore.QFileInfo(fpath))
```

Comment: This is working on linux only right?

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r I have not tried on anything other than Linux.